# update table by response of the inner query

Tags: postgresql

Trying to update the field in portfolio table with the help of inner query.

So this is the actual query which i'm trying as shown below:-

```
UPDATE portfolio SET "productTargetCheck"=1
WHERE "id" in (SELECT jsonb_agg("portfolioId") FROM uac WHERE "campaignId" IN (92738140924095,18631183844302));
```

so the select query(inner query) is returning array as value

```
SELECT jsonb_agg("portfolioId") FROM uac WHERE "campaignId" IN (92738140924095,18631183844302);
```

so this is the response i'm getting

```
                                     jsonb_agg                                      
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  ["cf69fe67-4409-4f5e-b48f-c051ad68d641", "eaf64075-25a4-424c-82fd-3d5238f19ed4"]
```

so in this response, it is the array of UUID
and taking those UUID I'm trying to update field in Portfolio table

Taking the response i'm of the select query and updating the field as shown below again:-

```
UPDATE portfolio SET "productTargetCheck"=1
WHERE "id"=(SELECT jsonb_agg("portfolioId") FROM uac WHERE "campaignId" IN (92738140924095,18631183844302));
```

i'm getting response as

```
pq: unsupported comparison operator: <uuid> = <jsonb>
```

Is the anyway that i can update the field with querying into second table?

Comment: Is this a MySQL question, or a PostgreSQL question? Please do not use both tags, unless both systems are involved. Also, please share more details about your attempt to resolve the problem

Comment: I found it out. It was very simple.

UPDATE portfolio SET "productTargetCheck"=1  WHERE "id" IN (SELECT ("portfolioId") FROM uac WHERE "campaignId" IN (298336564, 247863786, 223334372))